# jQuery inner error on paste event

Tags: jquery, copy, copy-paste, paste, handsontable

When I paste (CTRL+V), I have a jQuery error: TypeError: e is null

I have quite complicated data table solution with customized [Handsontable](https://handsontable.com/). It happens on special cases. I don't know how to handle this error, there's only jquery on the stacktrace.

Do you have any suggestions to me?

Thanks in advance.

The stacktrace:

```
n/</<()
jquery.js.xhtml:36
u()
jquery.js.xhtml:33
n/<()
jquery.js.xhtml:36
[58]</<.run()
jquery.js.xhtml:34
[25]</S.Core/this.runHooks()
jquery.js.xhtml:31
[86]</<.onDataChange/n.replace()
jquery.js.xhtml:38
[86]</<.onDataChange/<()
jquery.js.xhtml:38
u()
jquery.js.xhtml:33
[86]</<.onDataChange()
jquery.js.xhtml:38
[86]</<.enablePlugin/<()
jquery.js.xhtml:38
[56]</c.runLocalHooks/<()
jquery.js.xhtml:33
u()
jquery.js.xhtml:33
[56]</c.runLocalHooks()
jquery.js.xhtml:33
[85]</<.onChange()
jquery.js.xhtml:38
[85]</<.setObservedData/this.observer<()
jquery.js.xhtml:38
h()
jquery.js.xhtml:61
a()
jquery.js.xhtml:61
[85]</<.setObservedData()
jquery.js.xhtml:38
[86]</<.onAfterLoadData()
jquery.js.xhtml:38
[86]</<.enablePlugin/<()
jquery.js.xhtml:38
[58]</<.run()
jquery.js.xhtml:34
[25]</S.Core/this.loadData()
jquery.js.xhtml:30
afterCellChangedImpl()
jquery.js.xhtml:206
afterCellChanged()
jquery.js.xhtml:159
[58]</<.run()
jquery.js.xhtml:34
r()
jquery.js.xhtml:30
[25]</S.Core/this.setDataAtCell/<()
jquery.js.xhtml:30
r()
jquery.js.xhtml:30
n/<.checkIfQueueIsEmpty()
jquery.js.xhtml:30
o()
jquery.js.xhtml:30
[25]</S.Core/this.setDataAtCell()
jquery.js.xhtml:30
[25]</S.Core/f.populateFromArray()
jquery.js.xhtml:30
[25]</S.Core/this.populateFromArray()
jquery.js.xhtml:30
n()
jquery.js.xhtml:36
.copyPaste</r.prototype.triggerPaste/<()
```

Comment: The stacktrace tells us nothing without the actual code ?

Comment: I'm sorry, now I see, there are my methods in stacktrace, which I didn't see before, because it was targeted to jquery.js. I commented out the line, which was causing this, but I still have very weird behavior on paste event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys for disturbing, I finally fixed it. I just was frustrated, so I needed to write it about, but it probably wasn't anything you could help me. I had some wrong calls of js libraries there and some wrong js event handling.